# Display images stored on server

Tags: sql, database, image

Images paths are stored in sql database and images are stored in a folder "Albums" on server. I want to display those images using this code:
    `Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("/Albums/13/9622d79b-a6b3-4354-ae14-2fbd5f986c5425db");`
but this is not working. I have searched alot but couldn't find any solution. so please help me. I am using C# in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the server.mappath, you just need to use the absolute path of the image on the server, which is what appears you have (without the server.mappath).

Comment: my images are present in "Albums" folder and website is uploaded in another folder "te" within the root folder on server. now tell me how to pass image path to imageurl?

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath returns physical directory of given resource. So assign path of image with MapPath. Also make sure that the extension of image file is proper. Otherwise server will return HTTP 404.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/Albums/13/9622d79b-a6b3-4354-ae14-2fbd5f986c5425db.jpg";
```

In the code above, **/** at start denotes root of the server. So it is assumed that "Albums" is a folder located inside server root.

Comment: my website is uploaded on "httpdocs/images/te/" and images are present in "httpdocs/Albums/13/". How to give this path to my image url?

Comment: If your website root is `httpdocs`, the code above should work.